# CSS - float starts on a new line even though the width is set

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, cross-browser, webflow

I designed this website: https://cakesbystephaniemi.com

I used a combination of Webflow and my own knowledge of html and css to organize everything so that I could also make minor edits to the code after exporting it to host it on my client's server. I tested the website's responsiveness on multiple browsers and saw no issues, but now that the site is live I have other users on different desktop computers stating that the .png image at the top of the page is clipping into the text div I have floated right of the image slider. See photos:
[how it looks on my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpm9n.png) vs [how it looks on their device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boSMY.jpg)

Now I believe it looks like the div class="textbox-home" is at fault. When first writing the code I had this issue happen, but I fixed it by using exact math for the responsive widths of all the elements. So I assumed adjusting it's width to avoid overlap would work but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will answer your question, but i am using CSS code below every time in order to protect image or animation overflow over other elements :

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

So my solution was to wrap both the slider and the textbox in another div and set it to flex. This seems to work again when I view the files, but the server is slow to loading the changes to the live website. Hoping this works, but if it doesn't I will be back.